# What is this iOS Contol and How To Implement it?

Tags: ios, uicontrol

[image]

I'm confused about:

1) What type of control is the one shown in the picture above. I tried slider, it's not giving that same visual effect

2) How can I implement such a control exactly as seen on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two images one for selected and other for unselected and when any of the button is pressed change the image of button to selected image in button action and other two button will have unselected image.At a time only one button will be in selected state.

Answer (score 3):

It could be anything, but if i wanted to do it i would do it as a normal custom `UIView`, that has 3 `UIButtons`

This control will have a function like, setLevel:1,2,or 3
depending on the integer it will change the image of the UIButton accordingly

Answer (score 1):

1) If you just want those 3 points(Low, High, Medium) you can do as @Omar suggested in his answer.

2) But if you want all intermediate points and the middle (blue) dot as a handle, you can use [UISlider](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and change its minimumValue, maximumValue and thumb images.. See [this](http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=250) tutorial

Comment: Ya I have done this at first, but the client wants it be only those 3 points and be visually as on the image.. thanks for the response though Krishna!

Answer (score 0):

Now predefined iOS control have this presentation.

May be you can find in [cocoacontrols.org](http://www.cocoacontrols.org) or [binpress.com](http://www.binpress.com) to see if you can download a third controls made by developers.

Also, you can create yourself the control, on the two previous website, you can surely find a lot of control which mimic the display you want. You can download the source code, reverse engineering and build your own control

At worst, build this control from scratch with a UIView (maybe a UISlider) as super class.